# 'The "path" argument must be of type string. Received null' in electron-json-storage

Tags: node.js, electron

I'm using eletron-json-storage like this:

settings.js:

```
  const storage = require('electron-json-storage'); 
  const defaultStoragePath = storage.getDefaultDataPath(); 
  // Value: C:\Users\10467\AppData\Roaming\maplateditor\storage

  ...

  defaultStorage() {
    console.log("Check defaultStorage value");
    console.log(defaultStoragePath); 
    // C:\Users\10467\AppData\Roaming\maplateditor\storage
    storage.setDataPath(defaultStoragePath);
    console.log(storage.getDataPath());
    // C:\Users\10467\AppData\Roaming\maplateditor\storage
    return storage;
  }

  ...

  this.defaultStorage().get(...)
```

And I checked every times variable `defaultStoragePath` was sure to set.

But electron-json-storage causes error:

```
(anonymous) @ VM75 renderer_init.js:93
VM75 renderer_init.js:93 TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The "path" argument must be of type string. Received null
    at validateString (VM19 validators.js:124)
    at Object.resolve (VM28 path.js:139)
    at mkdirP (VM113 F:\github\MaplatEditor\node_modules\mkdirp\index.js:25)
    at VM91 F:\github\MaplatEditor\node_modules\electron-json-storage\lib\storage.js:527
    at nextTask (VM93 F:\github\MaplatEditor\node_modules\async\dist\async.js:5327)
    at next (VM93 F:\github\MaplatEditor\node_modules\async\dist\async.js:5334)
    at VM93 F:\github\MaplatEditor\node_modules\async\dist\async.js:972
    at VM91 F:\github\MaplatEditor\node_modules\electron-json-storage\lib\storage.js:524
    at nextTask (VM93 F:\github\MaplatEditor\node_modules\async\dist\async.js:5327)
    at Object.waterfall (VM93 F:\github\MaplatEditor\node_modules\async\dist\async.js:5337)
```

Is this a bug?
How can I avoid this?

Environments are:

node.js: 16.13.1
electron: 13.6.6
electron-json-storage: 4.5.0

===
Additional info:
This error not occurred with electron: 11.5.0

The difference of my code between electron: 11.5.0 and electron: 13.6.6 is:

On electron 11.5.0: Call settings.js code by:

```
  const settings = require('electron').remote.require('./settings').init();
```

On electron 13.6.6: Call settings.js code through `preload.js`:

```
  window.settingsBackend = require('./settings');
```

Maybe this difference causes different results..

Comment: What exact value are you setting `defaultStoragePath` to?  Did you try `storage.storage.getDataPath()` right after you set it to see if it stuck?

Comment: Thank you for comment, I added it in question

Comment: I tried this but not fixed
https://www.androidbugfix.com/2021/11/capacitor-community-electron-platform.html

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63855029/2328877
This said some modification on `.env` solve this problem, but modification itself is not sure...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found the reason...

I call "electron-json-storage" inside of "preload.js".
I don't know "preload.js" is worked on renderer process.
I must use electron-json-storage on main process.

I realized that under the contextIsolation environment, I need to completely rethink my architecture from the nodeIntegration era configuration.

====

I created example for using electron-json-storage under contextIsolation environment for people who will have similar question in future:
https://gist.github.com/kochizufan/a467c6b76390c6f1c41260614cb06a5c

This works well.
NOTE: Error handling or avoiding multiple registration of api are totally omitted in this example.

Any points for improvement are welcome.